# Check anagrams within list using dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a word list and need to find all the anagrams within the word list.

I have already tried to create the function/dictionary however I run into memory issues

```
words = word_list
sort_words = []
anagrams = {}
for word in words:
    word.split()
    word = ''.join(sorted(word))
    sort_words.append(word)

for i in range(len(sort_words)):
    word_anagram = []
    for j in range(len(sort_words)):
        if i == j:
            continue
        if sort_words[i] == sort_words[j]:
            word_anagram.append(words[j])
    anagrams[words[i]] = word_anagram 
print(anagrams)
```

Is there a different key I should use to get rid of the memory error? I think this will hep as there will be repeats in the anagrams that the function find. If so, what key should I use?

Comment: What memory issues or memory error are you getting? Please always post the full traceback of any exception you hit. Also, I suggest using a `collections.Counter` instead of sorting the words. It is a dictionary, it will count occurrences of each letter, and so you can compare two anagrams and their `Counter` representations will be equal.

Comment: IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal: That sounds like an issue with your Python interpreter, not with your code itself. Perhaps you should tell us more about your programming environment?

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2):

```
words = word_list
answer = {}
for word in words:
    answer.setdefault(''.join(sorted(word)), []).append(word)
```

Each word in `word_list` is sorted, and associated with that as the key.

Therefore, anagrams are associated by the sorted letters, and all anagrams appear in a list together.

This has linear space complexity, so you *shouldn't* run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your word is `"0123456789"`. As you can see the length of the string is 10. If you want to create anagrams like below:

```
0123456789
1023456789
1203456789
```

which the items are used only one time, you would get 10! possible anagrams. 10! equals to 3628800. Each word has 10 digits which means 10 bytes. 10! * 10 = 36288000 bytes. That means **36.288 MB**. I am ignoring the `"\n"` escape sequence in this case. If we need to consider this escape sequence, You would need 10! * 11 bytes which is equal to **39.9168 MB**.

If the length of the word becomes 11, you would need 439084800 bytes (11! * 11 = 439084800). And that equals to **439.0848 MB**. If we need to consider the `"\n"` escape sequence, this time you would need **479.0016 MB**.

If the length of the word becomes 12, you would need 5748019200 bytes (12! * 12 = 5748019200). And that equals to **5.7480192 GB**. If we need to consider the `"\n"` escape sequence, this time you would need **6.2270208 GB**.

So when making such calculations, you need to know whether the size of the data to be produced can be done by your hardware.